# Вызвать $this внутри функции

Tags: php, ооп

Вот класс

```
class ClassName{
    public $array = array('1','2');

    function __construct() {
        ....
    }

    function init() {

        function add_class($classes) {
            foreach( $this->array as $class ){
               array_push($classes, $class)
            }
            return  $classes;
        }
        add_filter('post_class', 'add_class');

    }

    function init2() {

        function add_metaboxes() {
            foreach( $this->array as $metaboxes ){
               $checked = ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'app_category_'.$metaboxes , true) ) ? 'checked' : '';

               echo '<input type="checkbox" '.$checked.' >';

            }
        }

        add_meta_box( 'app_category_box', 'BlaBlaBla', 'add_metaboxes');

    }
}
```

В ооп не силен, когда пытаюсь так сделать - пишет "**Using $this when not in object context in**"

Comment: а каков смысл такого объявления функции внутри функции класса? вы же просто объявляете обычную функцию при вызове `init`, она не бдует иметь отношения к классу вообще, поэтому и this там недоступен

Comment: есть смысл, нужно добавить хук в вп, то что там this  недоступен, я и так понял)

Comment: `$this->array` не работает (второй $ ошибочно написал)

Comment: поскольку тут (к счастью)  не все знакомы с WP, то объясните всю логику, которую вы хотите реализовать. Можете заюзать анонимную функцию, оно конечно не будет видно снаружи класса, как ваша текущая реализация. То есть пока что ваш класс и ваша функция вообще никак не связаны.

Comment: обновил код, вся идея в том что мне нужно использовать один и тот же массив в разных местах

Comment: может вам подойдет вариант с объявлением массива как static-поля и константы?

Comment: Можете показать на примере?

Comment: объявить как `public static $array = ...`, использовать как `ClassName::$array`, но в таком случае массив один для всех экземпляров класса, но мне кажется у вас класс создается только единожды.

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо

Comment: оформил ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде у вас имеется класс, в котором определены функции. В данных функциях, вы обяъвляете другие функции. Это просто объявления, к самому классу они не будут никак относится. После вызова метода `Init` у вас все так же будет оставаться класс, а также для вызова в других местах кода станет доступна функция `add_class`.

*Замечу, что при повторном вызове функции `init` интерпретатор упадет с ошибкой `fatal error` при попытке объявить заново функцию `add_class`.*

Поскольку объявленная функция ни коим боком не будет относится к классу (который ее объявил), то, конечно, речи о доступе к `$this` там быть  не может. О чем и сказано в сообщении об ошибке.

Как вариант решения (если используете данный массив единственном экземпляре) может стать объявление массива как *статического члена класса*.

```
public static $array = [1,2];
```

В дальнейшем для обращения к массиву из сторонних функций будут иметь следующий вид:

```
foreach( ClassName::$array as $class ){
}
```

Повторюсь, что статические свойства существуют в единственном экземпляре и одинаковы межде всеми экземплярами класса. Но по всей видимости, класс у вас используется тоже в единственном экземпляре.

Comment: А как же обычный `use` ? http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php. Или тупо передать как параметр? А сам код класса адовый...

Comment: @E_p дак ему именованную функцию надо определить, которую WP потом по имени дергает, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: по крайней мере я так понял, что WP должен выполнить функцию с заданным именем, и в сигнатуре там ничего нет, чтобы можно было как то передавать параметры. Но если нет, то конечно анонимки и параметры как вариант.

Comment: Одно точно, тимлида злого на автора вопроса нет...

Comment: @E_p злые тимлиды вообще WP не пользуют по-моему :)

Comment: Legacy, к сожалению, ни кто не отменял...